# Yesod Web application: where to store user settings

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm creating a web application(Yesod + sqlite) where users basically do a bunch of full text searches.
Users can set their preferences such as articles length, number of keyword matches etc.

What is the recommended way to store users preferences and settings?
I can of course store these settings in the database. So at each connection the user retrieves the settings from database and keep it in memory?

Comment: sounds like a good idea

Comment: Yeah, why not ? This seems to the most reasonable way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do store permanent user preferences in a database. That way the settings follow the user, irrespective of the user agent (device and/or browser) she uses to access your website. Further more, databases can be backed up offline by your database administrator and can easily be copied or shared with new servers. Settings in a database can also easily be aggregated for statistics on which preferences are unused and which are common, and which preferences correlate.

Storing them elsewhere, whether in a obscure, flat file on the webserver or in a HTTP cookie, would only be appropriate for transient settings that will not even be of statistical or historical interest later.